# Error when installing sylius sandbox

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm trying to install latest version of sylius sandbox and I get this error

```
ParameterNotFoundException: The service "sylius_sandbox.form.type.product_variants_grid" has a 
dependency on a non-existent parameter "sylius_assortment.model.product.class".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what is your question?

Nevertheless, this might be relevant:

https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusAssortmentBundle/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#24-012013

> 24-01.2013
>
> Remove the sylius_assortment prefix from services and models.
>
> Use sylius instead.

Comment: That's what I need. Thansk